# How to debug callback wrapping of java events in Matlab?

Tags: java, matlab, undocumented-behavior

I have designed several event listener patterns in Java, but not all cases are wrapped into callbacks when using MATLAB.

Sometimes, an event is just not wrapped into a callback, while other ones are wrapped.

In other cases, the presence of one event breaks all other event wrapping. I.e. no any callbacks found in class with such listener.

In third cases events are wrapped normally.

What are absolute requirements for an event being wrapped into a callback?

Is it possible to trace or debug this process?

Comment: Can you show us an example of how you are creating one of these "problematic" events?

Comment: They are very long for now. And while I will be shortening them, I probably see what matters myself :) Will post back when done.